# SequelizeEagerLoadingError: parent model is not associated to child

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

This is the parent model/table:

```
const { Sequelize, DataTypes } = require('sequelize');
const VerifyToken = require('./verifyToken');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const User = sequelize.define('User', {
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,

}, {
    tableName: 'users',
    timestamps: false,
    //syncOnAssociation: true
    hierarchy: true,
    underscored: true

});

User.associate = function (models) {
    const {VerifyToken} = models;

    User.hasOne(VerifyToken, {
        as: 'verify_tokens',
        foreign_key: 'user_id'
    });
};

return User;
};
```

This is the child model:

```
const User = require('./user');

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
const VerifyToken = sequelize.define('VerifyToken', {

    user_id: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    token: DataTypes.STRING,

}, {
    tableName: 'verify_tokens',
    hierarchy: true,
    underscored: true
});


VerifyToken.associations = function (models) {
    const {User} = models;

    VerifyToken.belongsTo(User);
};

return VerifyToken;
};
```

`models/index.js` file:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const basename = path.basename(__filename);
const env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';
const config = require(__dirname + '/../config/config.json')[env];
const db = {};

let sequelize;
if (config.use_env_variable) {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env[config.use_env_variable], config);
} else {
  sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, config);
}

fs
  .readdirSync(__dirname)
  .filter(file => {
    return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js');
  })
  .forEach(file => {
    const model = sequelize['import'](path.join(__dirname, file));
    db[model.name] = model;
  });

Object.keys(db).forEach(modelName => {
  if (db[modelName].associate) {
    db[modelName].associate(db);
  }
});

db.sequelize = sequelize;
db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

module.exports = db;
```

, but when I make a query like this:

```
const verifyToken = await models.VerifyToken.findOne({
    where: {
        token
    },
    include:{
        model: models.User
    }
});
```

I am getting this:

> SequelizeEagerLoadingError: User is not associated to VerifyToken!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Please correct **VerifyToken.associations** with **VerifyToken.associate**
2. Remove a redundant import of const VerifyToken = require('./verifyToken'); from the User model definition.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I did it 30 mins after the question. It was a stupid error ...